# Unable to view the data when file is opened after written using file cordova file plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap, cordova-plugin-file

I have used cordova file plugin to write data to a file inside application. The link that I refered to perform read and write operations is:

> https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

The thing is I am successfully able to write and read the data operations and also able to view the data in the console after the operations. But, the main issue that I am facing is when I opened the file for which I had performed write operation, say "sample.csv". The data that I had written was not visible.

Also, I wanted to create a new file using the same plugin i.e cordova-plugin-file. As of now, I could perform operations over an pre-existing file in my project. But, inspite of not getting any error no new file is generated. Currently I am running the project in the chrome browser. Not sure exactly if it will work only when run in android.

I had referred this link for the creation of the file:

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cordova/cordova_file_system.htm

Any suggestion regarding viewing the contents written over file could be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .csv files which were not able to open in the chrome browser of project was because the plugin will make operations over the files only belonging to android devices. When I opened the same file in android device, the file opened.